# I don't want to add duplicate data into my redux store array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, frontend

I want to add unique data into my store array, but seems to stuck while adding the data and duplicate data is getting pushed into array. I am using typescript.

So my slice function looks like this.

```
const initialState = {
  dropDownData:{
  programs: [],
  years: []
 }
}
```

```
const slice = createSlice({
  name:"filterSlice",
  initialState: initialState,
  reducers:{
     updateProgram:(state, action) => {
 state.dropDownData.programs = [...state.dropDownData.programs, action.payload];
   }
 }
});
```

I am calling this reducer function in this way: `dispatch(updateProgram(program))`

So the program i am getting is in the form of array.
But I don't need duplicate data from the program array.

So how to update my reducer function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Instead of this:**

`state.dropDownData.programs = [...state.dropDownData.programs, action.payload];`

**Use this:**

`state.dropDownData.programs = [...(new Set([...state.dropDownData.programs, action.payload]))];`

**Approach:**

- The javascript `Set` allows one to retain only unique elements from the parameter.
- Thus, when a `new Set` is created with elements from existing two arrays, the `Set` will keep only the unique elements.
- Next, we need to use the `...` spread-operator to transform the `Set` back into an array.

Answer (score 0):

i try this and works for me:

```
> addToMyList: (state, action: PayloadAction<Movie>) => {
>  if (!state.myList?.find((movie) => movie.id === action.payload.id)) {
>    state.myList = state.myList ? [action.payload, ...state.myList] : 
>     [action.payload];
>   }
> }
```